# Loading a jquery-ui dialogbox on clicking a link

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have an  tag as follows:

```
<a onClick="showDialog();"> 
    <?php Print $s; ?> 
</a>
```

In my `document.ready()` function, i have the `showDialog()` function

```
function showDialog()
{
    $('#userdata').dialog('open');
}
```

And i make the dialog not to appear, by including this in my document.ready() function

```
$("#userdata").dialog({autoOpen:false});
```

Also, in my body section, i have the "userdata" div element

```
<div id="userdata">hello</div>
```

But,when i click on the link, nothing happens.... But if i add an `alert()` inside the `showDialog()` function, it is getting triggered. can someone tell me how to display the jquery dialog box ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a link is clicked it will open content in dialog box.

```
var p = '<p>test test test test test test</p>';
$('a').click(function(){    
    $(p).dialog({
       ...
    });
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/msKZt/2/

Comment: The problem is that i dont have the link directly in the html page. The <a> tag is added by a php file inside a <div> tag in the html page. Because of that , html page is not able to find the <a> tag that was added by the php page. Is there a way around?

Comment: In that case instead of using `$('a').click(..)`. use live ex: `$('a').live('click', function(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

on your click event of the link add this

```
$('#ElementID').dialog('open');
```